# Using Trusted Root Certification Authorities for server certificate validation in HttpClient

Tags: c#, ssl, https, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created a self-signed certificate using

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout https-key.pem -out https.pem -days 365
```

then I created pkcs12 using (I have set the CN to my server's ip adress):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out https.pfx -inkey https-key.pem -in https.pem -password pass:123456
```

In my server a use the generated `https.pfx` file for https.

In my client I imported the generated certificate into the Windows' `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` (Current user and also local system).

When I send a HTTP request to the server from my client, I get

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task).
```

In chrome it says:

```
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from *** (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Does .NET Core 2.0's `HttpClient` use Windows certificate stores? What could be causing the issue.

Comment: I think you are having a windows credential issue.  For two PC to communicate in windows they must be in the same group.  If you are in a corporate Network then Group Policy Applies and you need to take to your MIS people to get the two PCs in same group.  A website is usually has guest credentials so a group is not required.  Trusted Root means the two PCs are in the same group and then a password is not required because windows credential are being used.  When windows credentials are used the user must have an account on both local and remote PCs.

Comment: @jdweng I have both the client and the server on the same PC.

Comment: Why do you think this is a certificate exception?  Usually I see different errors that what you are seeing for a certification error.   I would start by using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to get more info on error.  Also determine exactly what instruction in the code you are failing.

Comment: Is the certificate you created a proper SSL certificate? Also, Chrome (at least) requires SAN to be set in the certificate before it will accept the certificate. Do you set those properly? Also also, do you only have the certificate in the trusted root store or also elsewhere? Also also also, before attempting your HTTP client, check other clients (other browsers etc.) first to confirm that everything is working properly.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you create a small test application that you can use as a client to test the TLS configuration of the server.

You can use the [SslStream class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET to connect to a TLS endpoint and perform the negotiation.  It can return a much more understandable error message than the random HRESULT codes and unhelpful error messages that come out of SChannel.

The test tool can be nothing more than a WinForms app that contains the following code:

```
public static void q48873455()
{
    const string hostname = "localhost";
    var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    tcpClient.Connect(hostname, 443);
    var tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    using (var sslStream = new SslStream(tcpStream, false, ValidateServerCertificate))
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname);
    }
}


static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
   if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        return true;

    Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

    return false;
}
```

This code established a raw TCP connection to port 443, then uses `SslStream` to perform a TLS negotiation.  During that negotiation, the server will send its certificate, and `SslStream` will call the `ValidateServerCertificate()` method, passing the `certificate` that it received, and providing a value for `SslPolicyErrors` which indicates what SChannel thought of the certificate.

The `SslPolicyErrors` value is one of the values listed on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145055(v=vs.110).aspx) which indicate why (if at all) SChannel thinks the certificate is not trusted.

I tend to find that having a tool such as this around is very helpful when trying to work out why a given certificate is not trusted.

Hope this helps